# CoffeeScript : unexpected INDENT error

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying out CoffeeScript in my Rails 3.1 app. However, I am not able 
to figure out how to break long lines in CoffeeScript without getting the 
above error

For example, how/where would you break the following line of code

```
alert x for x in [1,2,3,4,5]  when x > 2
```

if you wanted something like

```
alert x for
  x in [1,2,3,4,5]
  when x > 2
```

In my vimrc, I have set

```
 ts=2, sw=2 and I expand tabs.
```

And yet, I cannot get something as simple as the line above to work properly.

My Gemfile.lock shows coffee-script-2.2.0 with coffee-script-source 1.1.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a comprehension that is too long you can break it with `\` as @brandizzi mentions, but I think you might have better luck just using comprehensions where they make sense and expanding to 'regular' code where they don't:

```
alert x for x in [1,2,3,4,5]  when x > 2
```

...can be rewritten as...

```
for x in [1,2,3,4,5]
  alert x if x > 2
```

...or even...

```
for x in [1,2,3,4,5]
  if x > 2
    alert x
```

In other words, comprehensions are syntactic sugar for short, concise snippets - you don't have to use them for everything.

Comment: Exactly. CoffeeScript's `for`/`while`/`until`, like `if`/`unless`, can be used either postfix or prefix. If prefixed, you need to use either indentation or `then`.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to spread a comprehension out over multiple lines, which isn't allowed.  It either needs to be on one line, or be a proper loop.  Your one line version works as expected, so I'll show the loop version:

```
for x in [1..5] when x > 2
  alert x
```

You may find it helpful to toss small things like this into the CoffeeScript compiler at http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/ to see if they're compiling to what you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the inner details of CoffeeScript syntax, so I cannot say what is going wrong in detail. The error is a bit clear, however: you cannot put a newline between the `for` and its iterator variable. Also, you did not get this error *yet*, but you cannot put a newline between the iterated object and the `when` clause. However, if you really want to do it, it is easy: put backslashes at the end of the first and second lines.

```
console.log x for \
    x in [1,2,3,4,5] \
    when x > 2
```