# How do I indent list comprehension in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, indentation

I have the following line of `CoffeeScript`:

```
names = (mail.folder for mail in @data when mail.service_name is service.name).unique()
```

This line is too long, so it won't pass linting by `CoffeeLint`.

I'm trying to break it, but I always get indentation errors by `CoffeeLint`.

What is the proper way to indent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most readable version of that without getting overly lengthy:

```
names =
  (for mail in @data when mail.service_name is service.name
    mail.folder).unique()
```

You can't split list comprehensions over multiple lines, but a normal for loop can also return a value, so using one of those solves the problem.  If you're willing to grant an extra line, there's no need for the awkward parentheses around the loop:

```
names =
  for mail in @data when mail.service_name is service.name
    mail.folder
names = names.unique()
```

Finally, the indentation of the `for` line is up to you; I find my first version more readable but this is also valid:

```
names =
(for mail in @data when mail.service_name is service.name
  mail.folder).unique()
```

Answer (score 4):

This [compiles fine](http://goo.gl/D7wwa):

```
names = (mail.folder for mail in @data \
         when mail.service_name is service.name).unique()
```

You can also invert the `for ... when` and the expression:

```
names = (for mail in @data when mail.service_name is service.name
           mail.folder).unique()
```

Comment: I get *PARSE ERROR ON LINE 1: UNEXPECTED 'INDENT'* on your first solution. Your second solution seems to work ok.

Comment: @jackwanders Yes, you are right, i don't know how i missed that :S. I fixed that now with a line continuator `\`. Does it work that way? (the link show point to an updated exmaple in coffeescript.org)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently splitting list comprehension over multiple lines is not allowed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553292